# MonoGame cannot load a Song as a non-content file

Tags: xna, load, assets, monogame

I've created a game in XNA 4.0 and now want to port it to MonoGame. I'm using the exact same code for my LoadContent method as I did in the original game. However, MonoGame fails to load a song from the content folder and returns an error saying `Could not load Example asset as a non-content file`. I'm using the following line of code to do it.

```
Song song = songLoader.Load<Song>("Example");
```

The song is in the WMA format with a compiled XNB file in the same folder. Both files are set to "Copy if newer". How do I fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to MonoGame, the incompatible port of XNA

Comment: Did you `Build` the project from the `Content` app?